# Intercepting python interpreter code before it executes

Tags: python, interpreter

Is it possible to intercept interpreter's code before it executes?

Let's say I want to handle a case like:

```
>>> for f in glob.glob('*.*'): # I'd like to intercept this code before it executes 
...     something_to_do(f)     # and play with it in some dangerous fashion :)
...
ERROR: Using glob not allowed. # e.g.
```

But there are tons of other examples (like altering the code, or sending it somewhere).

I can write my own interpreter, but that's not really the point.

Comment: Are you trying to intercept the use the `glob` module, or just the `glob` function? Is it okay for the program to define it's own `glob`? That is, are you just interested in intercepting a specific function, or intercepting the behaviour?

Comment: Also, how do you execute the code that you wish to intercept? eg. `python somescript.py` or `exec(some_string)`, or ...?

Comment: @Dunes You're missing the point, the "glob" doesn't matter. I gues it would be nice if it would be some kind of function that I would decorate and than execute anyway, so I would loose any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it by creating new module which starts new interpreter instance and do whatever.

I just put the code below in the module and import it.

```
import code

class GlobeFilterConsole(code.InteractiveConsole):
    def push(self, line):
        self.buffer.append(line)
        source = "\n".join(self.buffer)

        if 'glob' in source: # do whatever you want with the source
            print('glob usage not allowed')
            more = False
        else:
            more = self.runsource(source, self.filename)

        if not more:
            self.resetbuffer()
        return more


console = GlobeFilterConsole()
console.interact()
```